# Fix usb permissions

Tags: usb

After getting a normal user account like everyone should have, I decided to mount my usb stick and move some stuff. Then, it turned out that the usb privileges are messed up (somehow); I can't write or execute `/media/usbxyz`. This means that I can't unmount my usb stick. With what privileges should have the user been created?

Edit: Someone asked for `mount` and `id`, so here.

```
***:~/Desktop> mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=2001728k,nr_inodes=500432,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=404388k,mode=755)
/dev/sda2 on / type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset,clone_children)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.perf_event)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=33,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
cgmfs on /run/cgmanager/fs type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=100k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/user/1001 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=404388k,mode=700,uid=1001,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1001/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1001,group_id=1000)`

***:~/Desktop> id
uid=1001(***) gid=1000(***) groups=1000(***)
```

Comment: Can you run the command `mount` without arguments, pick out the line of its output corresponding to the device you are talking about and [edit] your question to share that please? Also, what groups does your user belong to (output of `groups` or better `id` please)?

Comment: What format, NTFS, FAT, etc. is the drive? Some formats, such as NTFS will automatically mount without exec permission. What method are you using to unmount the usb stick? What permissions do the directory and files currently have?

Comment: Also, you can take ownership of the usb file in UNIX. In UNIX, you can pretty much do anything; you may have to remount in order to do that though.

Comment: @mchid Of course I can do that, but I won't, because that's supposed to be owned by root.

Comment: @mchid It's a vfat drive.

Comment: @ByteCommander id: `UID: 1001, GID: 1000, groups: 1000`

Comment: That is just a tiny part of the information I asked for. Please [edit] the question and add the full output of `id` and the full output line of `mount` that belongs to your USB drive.

Comment: @ByteCommander There.

Comment: There is no mounted USB drive visible in the output you gave me. Seems like I haven't stated explicitly enough that I mainly need the line corresponding to your mounted USB drive, so it must be connected and mounted when you run the `mount` command.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have 2 different issues.

First up with mounting: the `mount`/`umount` commands requires root privileges, but as a user you don't typically use it. Ubuntu have configured and installed udisks2. So you can just click a disk in file-manager, and it will get mounted. If you insist on command line, you can do it with `udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sdxn` *(you do not point a directory because `udisks2` is configured to use a specific one, usually a `/media/username`)*.

The problem with permissions on the stick is most likely because whole stick is owned by root. That happens when a filesystem just created; e.g. after `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdxn`, and mounting it, you'll get an empty directory owned by root.

Just run something like `sudo chown -R youruser:youruser /media/youruser/yourusbdrive` to fix it.

Comment: That would be convenient, but as it turns out, I don't have sudo privileges on this machine. Also, don't you think `/media` should be owned by root? Also, the stick gets mounted under `/media/usb0`, not under my username.

Comment: @pwfihscjmwe yes, `/media` is owned by root, as is `/media/username`. udisks2 is using a combination of setuid bit and polkit rules; the directory being special in that things mounted in there can not be ran with setuid. Anyway, the fact that it's mounted under `/media` as opposed to `/media/username` is odd. Did you change anything in… err… on Ubuntu it's `/lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks2.rules`, I guess? You said you created a new user — does it behave the same way for the old one? What Ubuntu version are you using btw?

Comment: @pwfihscjmwe btw, you added in other comments that the file system of stick is vfat. It's an important bit of info, because vfat doesn't support unix rights, so `chown` won't do anything. You need to provide the info ByteCommander asked for.

Comment: The machine runs 16.04, and as far as I know that file wasn't tampered with. My user is the only user without sudo, so I don't know how it would behave for the older users (on this machine) without sudo.

Comment: @pwfihscjmwe what's the deal with `sudo` btw? Does it say that "user isn't in sudoers file", or what? I probably miss some important bit of information, but right now this all so weird; if it weren't for GNU/Linux, I'd assume you're using pirated Ubuntu  Was this user created at the time of system installation, or some time later?

Comment: No, I just wasn't given sudo privs, because the system administrator deemed I a) didn't need them and b) wouldn't know how to use them; with which I agree. Also: yes, I am not in the sudoers file.

Comment: @pwfihscjmwe, If you have no superuser `sudo` privileges, and you cannot write or execute files on a USB drive, you must ask the administrator of the computer to help you. The answer should be either *'yes, I will fix it for you'* or *'no, it is against our policy to let regular users  write or execute files on a USB drive'* or something meaning the same thing.

Comment: @pwfihscjmwe ok, so besides you there's also a sysadmin, who probably configured it for their usecase. Now this starts making sense; I didn't consider this because in this case I agree with prev. commenter — why wouldn't you just ask sysadmin.

Comment: @Hi-Angel The thing is, the sysadmin didn't tamper with usb or any such thing. In fact, the sysadmin thinks this has something to do with my privileges. As such, I turned to askubuntu.